# How to manipulate PostProcessing effects settings during execution with c#?

Tags: unity, c#, post-processing

I need to change the intensity value of my current Vignette effect depending in specific conditions.
So far I haven't been able to achieve this. Please help!

*Image of what I want to achieve:*
[image]

*My setup:*

- Unity 2019.3.5f1 with URP implemented
- Post Processing Package (v2) installed
- Scene with a GameObject + Volume component with Vignette and Bloom effect overrides added
- A monobehaviour component script in the very same GameObject from above

*My monobehaviour script:*

```
using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;

 public class PostProcessingHandler : MonoBehaviour
 {
   private PostProcessVolume _ppv;
   private Vignette _vignette;

   // Vignette intensity values
   [SerializeField, Range(0f, 1f)]
   private float _lowIntensity = 0.25f;
   [SerializeField, Range(0f, 1f)]
   private float _highIntensity = 0.5f;

   private void Start()
   {
     _ppv = GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>();
     Debug.Log(_ppv);
   }
 }
```

When I try to retrieve PostProcessingVolume component to get it's profile (and further layer manipulation) I always get **"null"**.

*Image of my setup:*
[image]

I've seen several guides/posts and even Unity documentation but I cannot get past that starting point of getting the PostProcessingVolume component, what am i missing?

Comment: could it be that the component you want to pick is of type 'Volume' and not 'PostProcessVolume'?

Comment: instead of "Debug.Log(GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>());" I tried "Debug.Log(GetComponent<Volume>());".
In this last case, Volume is not a valid component type, not even letting me compile correctly. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually has a tricky way to do it. You need to grab the `PostProcessValue` and then grab the effect that you want to change, in your case the `Vignette`. After that, you will need to "Override" the values, that is the key. Here is an example I did based on the Unity documentation:

```
public PostProcessVolume volume; //Assigned with the editor
Vignette vignette; //The post processing effect you want to change

void Start()
{
    vignette= volume.profile.GetSetting<Vignette>(); //Grab the value of the post processing effect

    vignette.smoothness.Override(0.5f); //override the effect that you want with the value you need.
}
```

As you can see, the "Override" is the key to actually make it work. You can see more in [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Manipulating-the-Stack.html).